# Error while exploding a struct column in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe whose schema looks like this:

```
event: struct (nullable = true)
|    | event_category: string (nullable = true)
|    | event_name: string (nullable = true)
|    | properties: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    | ErrorCode: string (nullable = true)
|    |    | ErrorDescription: string (nullable = true)
```

I am trying to explode the `struct` column `properties` using the following code:

```
df_json.withColumn("event_properties", explode($"event.properties"))
```

But it is throwing the following exception:

> ```
> cannot resolve 'explode(`event`.`properties`)' due to data type mismatch: 
> input to function explode should be array or map type, 
> not StructType(StructField(IDFA,StringType,true),
> ```

How to explode the column `properties`?

Comment: @user8371915 As that question has been marked as a duplicate of this question your close vote would now cause cyclical duplicate navigation (and isn't valid if tried now)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `explode` in an `array` or `map` *columns* so you need to convert the `properties` `struct` to `array` and then apply the `explode` function as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df_json.withColumn("event_properties", explode(array($"event.properties.*"))).show(false)
```

You should have your desired requirement

Comment: how can explode as Map. I need key name too

Comment: what is the array function you use? Is this the pyspark ArrayType data type function? or is this a sql func usually imported as F.<func>?

Comment: array is the spark sql functions that I imported

Answer (score 8):

as the error message says, you can only explode array or map types, not struct type columns.

You can just do

```
df_json.withColumn("event_properties", $"event.properties")
```

This will generate a new column `event_properties`, which is also of struct-type

If you want to convert every element of the struct to a new column, then you cannot use `withColumn`, you need to do a `select` with a wildcard `*`:

```
df_json.select($"event.properties.*")
```

Answer (score 0):

You  may use following to flatten the struct. Explode does not work for struct as error message states.

```
val explodeDF = parquetDF.explode($"event") { 
case Row(properties: Seq[Row]) => properties.map{ property =>
  val errorCode = property(0).asInstanceOf[String]
  val errorDescription = property(1).asInstanceOf[String]
  Event(errorCode, errorDescription, email, salary)
 }
}.cache()
display(explodeDF)
```