# Flattening Maptype column in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have a pyspark DataFrame with a `MapType` column and want to explode this into all the columns by the name of keys

```python
root
 |-- a: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: long (valueContainsNull = true)
```

I want to do `sp_test.select('a.*')`
but getting an error:

> AnalysisException: 'Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: `ArrayBuffer(a)`;'

If we know all the keys, this can be achieved by doing

```python
sp_test.select(['a.%s'%item for item in ['a','b']]).show()
```

but i would like to remove key dependency

If we have a StrucType column, this can be achieved easily by doing `display(nested_df.select('*', 'nested_array.*'))`

```python
root
 |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- field2: long (nullable = true)
 |-- nested_array: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- nested_field1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- nested_field2: long (nullable = true)
```

I have some doubts:

1. can `MapType` be casted as `StructType`?
2. can we query sub-keys directly from `MapType`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48331272/exploding-structtype-as-maptype-spark- This is not same but, you can try looking for some options in here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**TL;DR:** There's no easy way to do what you're asking unless you know the possible keys ahead of time.

Let me use an example to try to explain why and what your options are.

First, create the following DataFrame:

```python
data = [({'a': 1, 'b': 2},), ({'c':3},), ({'a': 4, 'c': 5},)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["a"])
df.show()
#+-------------------+
#|                  a|
#+-------------------+
#|Map(a -> 1, b -> 2)|
#|        Map(c -> 3)|
#|Map(a -> 4, c -> 5)|
#+-------------------+
```

which has the following schema:

```python
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- a: map (nullable = true)
# |    |-- key: string
# |    |-- value: long (valueContainsNull = true)
```

> 1. can `MapType` be casted as `StructType`?

The simple answer is no (at least not not efficiently), unless you know the keys ahead of time.

The difference between the `MapType` and the `StructType` is that the key-value pairs for the maps are row-wise independent. That is not the case for a `StructType` column- in a struct column, all of the rows have the same struct fields.

For this reason, spark can't easily infer what columns to create from the map. (Remember that spark operates on each row in parallel). On the other hand, exploding a struct into columns is straightforward because all of the columns are known ahead of time.

So if you knew the keys, you can make a struct type via:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df_new = df.select(
    f.struct(*[f.col("a").getItem(c).alias(c) for c in ["a", "b", "c"]]).alias("a")
)
df_new.show()
#+-------------+
#|            a|
#+-------------+
#|   [1,2,null]|
#|[null,null,3]|
#|   [4,null,5]|
#+-------------+
```

And the new schema is:

```python
df_new.printSchema()
#root
# |-- a: struct (nullable = false)
# |    |-- a: long (nullable = true)
# |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
# |    |-- c: long (nullable = true)
```

> 2. can we query sub-keys directly from MapType?

Yes, (as shown above) you can use the [`getItem()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.getItem) which will get an item at an index out of a list, or by key out of a map.

---

If you don't know the keys, your only option is to `explode` the map into rows, `groupby` and `pivot`.

```python
df.withColumn("id", f.monotonically_increasing_id())\
    .select("id", f.explode("a"))\
    .groupby("id")\
    .pivot("key")\
    .agg(f.first("value"))\
    .drop("id")\
    .show()
#+----+----+----+
#|   a|   b|   c|
#+----+----+----+
#|null|null|   3|
#|   1|   2|null|
#|   4|null|   5|
#+----+----+----+
```

In this case, we need to create an `id` column first so that there's something to group by.

The `pivot` here can be expensive, depending on the size of your data.

Comment: What if the map is nested?