# input to function explode should be array or map type, not struct

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pandas-explode

I have the following data.

```py
data = [
    [
        "2022-12-12",
        ["IND", "u1", [["auction_1", [[1,20], [2,12]]], ["auction_2", [[1,5], [2,7]]]]],
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-12",
        ["USA", "u2", [["auction_1", [[1,8], [2,12]]], ["auction_2", [[1,11], [2,4]]]]],
    ],
]
```

I have the following schema

```py
actionSchema = T.StructType([
    T.StructField("amountSpent", T.LongType()),
    T.StructField("timeSpent", T.LongType())
])

actionsSchema = T.StructType(
    [T.StructField("action1", actionSchema), T.StructField("action2", actionSchema)]
)

userSchema = T.ArrayType(
    T.StructType(
        [
            T.StructField("refferalId", T.StringType()),
            T.StructField("actions", actionsSchema),
        ]
    )
)

dataSchema = T.StructType(
    [
        T.StructField("country", T.StringType()),
        T.StructField("userId", T.StringType()),
        T.StructField("users", userSchema),
    ]
)

schema = T.StructType(
    [T.StructField("date", T.StringType()), T.StructField("data", dataSchema)]
)
```

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
df.printSchema()

# it has the following schema
```

```
root
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- userId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- users: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- refferalId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- actions: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- action1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- amountSpent: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- timeSpent: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- action2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- amountSpent: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- timeSpent: long (nullable = true)
```

I would like to have to data in the below format for further analysis.

```js
date, country, userId, refferalId, action, amountSpent, timeSpent
2022-12-31, IND, 123, 123213,      action1, 5,          56
```

```
display(df.select(F.explode("data")))
# cannot resolve 'explode(data)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be an array or map type
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

If we can not explode any `StructType` how can I achieve the above data format?

I went through these questions also, but didn’t get much help -> [Error while exploding a struct column in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48315442/error-while-exploding-a-struct-column-in-spark)

Answer (score 0):

You must explode data.users :

```
df.select('date', 'data.country', 'data.userId', F.explode('data.users').alias('info'))
```

For the actions you need a query like below (after exploding data.users):

```
.select('date', 'country', 'userId', 'info.refferalId', F.explode('actions').alias('actionInfo'))
```

But because you defined actions as struct it can't be exploded. If you change its schema to list the code will works fine

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a task where you need to transform a bunch of your data to get it to the form you want. You'll need a combination of the `pyspark.sql.functions` to get where you want.

If we start from your `df`:

```
output = df.select("date", "data.country", "data.userId", explode(col("data.users")).alias("users")) \
           .select("date", "country", "userId", "users.*") \
           .withColumn("actions", explode(array(
               struct("actions.action1.*", lit("action1").alias("action")),
               struct("actions.action2.*", lit("action2").alias("action"))
               )
           )) \
           .select("date", "country", "userId", "refferalId", "actions.*")

output.printSchema()
root
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- userId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- refferalId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- amountSpent: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timeSpent: long (nullable = true)
 |-- action: string (nullable = false)

output.show()
+----------+-------+------+----------+-----------+---------+-------+
|      date|country|userId|refferalId|amountSpent|timeSpent| action|
+----------+-------+------+----------+-----------+---------+-------+
|2022-12-12|    IND|    u1| auction_1|          1|       20|action1|
|2022-12-12|    IND|    u1| auction_1|          2|       12|action2|
|2022-12-12|    IND|    u1| auction_2|          1|        5|action1|
|2022-12-12|    IND|    u1| auction_2|          2|        7|action2|
|2022-12-12|    USA|    u2| auction_1|          1|        8|action1|
|2022-12-12|    USA|    u2| auction_1|          2|       12|action2|
|2022-12-12|    USA|    u2| auction_2|          1|       11|action1|
|2022-12-12|    USA|    u2| auction_2|          2|        4|action2|
+----------+-------+------+----------+-----------+---------+-------+
```

The operations, transformation per transformation:

- The first, `select` statement unwraps the `data` struct and explodes the `data.users` array
- Second, `select` statement unwraps the `users` struct
- Third, `withColumn` statement is a bit more complicated. At this point we have 2 structs (`action1` and `action2`) that have the same schema. What we're doing here is:

  - adding a literal column, `action` with either value `action1` or `action2` to our `actions` columns
  - putting those 2 similar columns in an array using the `array` function
  - exploding that array
- Fourth, select statement is to unwrap the `actions` struct that we created

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot explode structs. You can only explode arrays or maps. The first step you need to take is to explode `data.users` (and not just data). You can do it this way:

```py
users = df\
    .withColumn("s", F.explode("data.users"))\
    .select("date", "data.country", "data.userId", "s.*")
users.show()
```

```
+----------+-------+------+----------+------------------+
|      date|country|userId|refferalId|           actions|
+----------+-------+------+----------+------------------+
|2022-12-12|    IND|    u1| auction_1|{{1, 20}, {2, 12}}|
|2022-12-12|    IND|    u1| auction_2|  {{1, 5}, {2, 7}}|
|2022-12-12|    USA|    u2| auction_1| {{1, 8}, {2, 12}}|
|2022-12-12|    USA|    u2| auction_2| {{1, 11}, {2, 4}}|
+----------+-------+------+----------+------------------+
```

From there, you want to explode the actions but as before, you cannot explode structs. To overcome that, you can convert it into an array of structs.

```py
users\
    .withColumn("actions", F.array(
        [ F.struct(
            F.lit(f"action{i}").alias("action"),
            F.col("actions")[f"action{i}"].alias("meta")
        ) for i in [1, 2] ]
    ))\
    .withColumn("action", F.explode("actions"))\
    .select("date", "country", "userId", "refferalId", "action.action", "action.meta.*")\
    .show()
+----------+-------+------+----------+-------+-----------+---------+
|      date|country|userId|refferalId| action|amountSpent|timeSpent|
+----------+-------+------+----------+-------+-----------+---------+
|2022-12-12|    IND|    u1| auction_1|action1|          1|       20|
|2022-12-12|    IND|    u1| auction_1|action2|          2|       12|
|2022-12-12|    IND|    u1| auction_2|action1|          1|        5|
|2022-12-12|    IND|    u1| auction_2|action2|          2|        7|
|2022-12-12|    USA|    u2| auction_1|action1|          1|        8|
|2022-12-12|    USA|    u2| auction_1|action2|          2|       12|
|2022-12-12|    USA|    u2| auction_2|action1|          1|       11|
|2022-12-12|    USA|    u2| auction_2|action2|          2|        4|
+----------+-------+------+----------+-------+-----------+---------+
```